# Sr5 Shadowrun Technomancers in space?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, technomancer, outer-space

Are technomancers gods in space compared to all other magic archetypes? I've heard in space Magic users are subject to a -6 to -12 penalty to their magic (i.e., 0 for everyone), assensing doesn't work or leads to insanity and drain causes you to explode.

But Technomancers use a different stat for their powers correct? Would a technomancer rule unchecked in space? Should we retire all our magic users as worthless and make technomancers instead?

Comment: I changed the space tag to outer-space to be a littler more descriptive; we haven’t been using such a tag, but searching “outer space” yields some results where it would be a helpful tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technomancers do not suffer from being away from the Manasphere in space.

However, being in areas without at least a basic Wi-Fi is very distracting, and without a Matrix connection Technomancers generally feel uneasy.

This can be alleviated by having a couple of comlinks to create a *background* of nodes and traffic, but the slow connection to the matrix can be **quite** bothersome: In most of space, you are either under Static Zone 5 or 6 (satellite uplink or no matrix access at all) as a baseline.<sup>1</sup>

However, Spacetravel and runs in Zurich Orbital or similar aren't much of a topic in SR5. The most recent depiction of what space feels like for Technomancers was in the SR4 Emergence and Hazard Pay books.

<sup>1 - SR5 Core p.230</sup>